# Add a row on top of table generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a mis calculation in a table structure. The code beneath is for a lotto game (a known piece of code I think ;))

Is there a way to add a row on top of the table filled with a numbers? I really don't know how to do this.

http://www.coldcharlie.nl/lotto/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

 var players = {
    Joop   : ["6","8","16","18","26","28","32","36","38","41"],
    Marijke: ["7","10","14","18","24","29","30","34","39","40"],
    Michel : ["4","5","11","16","21","27","33","36","42","44"],
    Mario  : ["6","9","18","25","32","35","39","40","43","45"],
    Diana  : ["2","6","8","17","22","23","33","36","42","45"],
    Agnes  : ["3","5","10","15","26","29","32","37","41","44"],
    Chris  : ["5","7","8","9","11","12","16","28","30","32"],
    Jeannette: ["1","2","4","7","8","11","13","28","30","38"],
    Wieger: ["1","2","3","7","10","13","14","22","23","27"],
    Anita: ["6","13","15","17","21","26","32","33","43","45"],
    Thea: ["1","3","5","7","10","17","19","20","22","38"],
    Danny: ["3","7","11","15","22","28","32","37","40","43"],
    Cindy: ["2","4","16","18","21","24","33","38","41","44"],
    Hanneke: ["1","3","4","12","18","21","25","30","36","40"],
    Willem: ["3","9","17","21","27","33","35","39","41","42"]
},

draws = [
    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 08-08-2009',
          picks:[2, 13, 15, 18, 21, 41]
    },

    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 15-08-2009',
      picks:[6, 19, 24, 25, 35, 37]
    },

    {
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 22-08-2009',
      picks:[8, 17, 23, 26, 37, 42]
    },

{
    when: 'Datum: Zaterdag 29-08-2009',
      picks:[1, 11, 31, 39, 42, 43]
    }
];



var buildPlayers = function(){
    var cont = $("#players"), table = $('<table></table>');
    for( player in players ){
    if ( players.hasOwnProperty( player ) ) {
        var tr = $('<tr><th>' + player + '</th></tr>').appendTo(table),
            len = players[player].length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var td = $('<td/>') 
     td.addClass("loss")
    .addClass("pick_" + players[player][i]) // add the class to the td  
    .text( players[player][i] )
    .appendTo ( tr );

    }


    var winning = $('<td>').addClass('winning-col').appendTo(tr);

        cont.append( table );
    }
    }
};


var buildDraws = function(){
    var cont = $("#draws");
    for(var i = 0; i < draws.length; i++){
    var html = ["<div class='draw'>","<h4 class='drawNum'>Trekking "+(i+1)+"</h3></p>","<div class='date'>"+draws[i].when+"</div>","<ol class='picks'>"];

    for(var j = 0; j < draws[i].picks.length; j++) {
        var img = '<img src="http://www.lotto.nl/static/images/ballen/lotto/l'
        + draws[i].picks[j]
        + '.jpg" alt="'
        + draws[i].picks[j]
        + '" />';
        html.push("<li>"+img+"</li>");
        showWin(draws[i].picks[j]);
    }



    html.push("</ol>","</div>");
    cont.append(html.join(""));
    }
};

var showWin = function(winNum){
    $(".pick_"+winNum).removeClass("loss").addClass("win");
};


$(function(){
    buildPlayers();
    buildDraws();
    function countWinning() {
    $('#players table tr').each(function() {
        var winning = $('td.win', this), total = 0;
        winning.each(function(i,num) {
        total+= parseInt( $(this).text(), 10);
        });

      $(".winning-col", this)
  .text($("td.win", this).length)
  .addClass("hilighted");

    });
    }
    countWinning();
});


})();

</script>
```

Comment: This is answered in another thread [link!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17860906/2443988)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can also do that using [insertBefore](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertBefore):

```
$('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>').insertBefore('table > tbody > tr:first');
```

or with [before](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content):

```
$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

or with [prependTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo#selector):

```
$("<tr><td>prependTo</td></tr>").prependTo("table > tbody");
```

Comment: I believe prependTo is the best option because it works even when the tbody is empty. The others rely on there being an existing first tr.

Comment: Does anyone know what this notation is called? `table > tbody` etc? EDIT: Answered my own question ["Child Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: Is it correct to say that the first two won't work if there are NO starting rows (<tr>) in the table?

Comment: Do you guys know how to do this to a particular table? say you have multiple tables on the same page, but you want to insert to a table who's id=table1

Comment: Using prepend, prepended  the row before my thead.. Wonder why.

Comment: Love the `insertBefore` and `prependTo`, but with both; on page refresh it goes to the bottom of the list. Any insights on how to persist the prepend through page refreshes?

Answer (score 40):

JQuery:

```
$("#myTable tbody").prepend("<tr><td>...contents...</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I can fit this part in?

Comment: Wherever you wanted to "add a row on top of the table filled with a numbers".

Comment: When I add this code to the numbers table, a lot of columns on top of eachother are added, not a row on top of the table.

Comment: @Chris: You need to add as many `<td></td>` elements as you have columns. It sounds like you are adding a row with just one column element in it, into a table that has more than one column.

Comment: @ZED how would you write this same code but if you had the table id. for example <table id="table1">....

Answer (score 19):

Use the `insertRow()` method on your `<tbody>`

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable'),
    tbody = myTable.tbodies[0],
    tr = tbody.insertRow(-1)  // puts it at the start
;

var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "Something";
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Comment: How could this fit into my table, I don't have a clue.

Comment: @Chris Charabaruk - actually, this question was tagged jQuery and Javascript. The two are not mutually exclusive, furthermore the OP does not ask specifically for a jQuery solution, so this is a good answer. Downvote removed.

Comment: thanks karim. (and there was no jquery tag when I answered...)

Comment: I'm really lost, I don't have clue where to put all these pieces of code, can someone please make an example out of the code I supplied?

Comment: I guess things have changed since 2009, and this post still pops up as the most relevant search 2020. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp `The value of -1 can also be used, this results in a new row being inserted at the last position.`. You probably want to do `insertRow(0)` *(or `1` if you have a header)* in 2020. Also, `tbodies` should be `tBodies` but isn't really relevant, because you should call `insertRow()` on the table object directly these days, `myTable.insertRow(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a row on top of table with a fade background:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('<tr class="anim highlight"><td>new text</td></tr>')
    .hide()
    .prependTo('table tbody')
    .fadeIn("slow")
    .addClass('normal');
});
```

Add background transition animation:

```
.anim {  
  transition: background 5s linear;
}
.highlight{
  background: #FF3333; 
}
.normal {  
  background: transparent;  
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/qdPAe/699/

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
 var newHtml = '<div/>';

 $('#tBody').html(newHtml + $('#tBody').html());
```