# Inserting a new row after a specific row in the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to design an invoice using bootstrap table and forms, i got the code to dynamically add and delete rows at the end of the table using jquery, but i want to to be able to add rows after any row inside the table.

I've tried many similar answers from here using `append()`,`prepend()` and `insertBefore()` but couldn't get it to work.

```js
$(function () {

    $("#insertRow").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var newRow = $("<tr class='d-flex'>");
        var cols = '';

        // Table columns
cols += '<td class="col-2 border"><div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="slno"></div></td>';
cols += '<td class="col-4 border text-center"><div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex"><textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="3"></textarea></div></td>';
cols += '<td class="col-2 border"><div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="slno"></div></td>';
cols += '<td class="col-3 border text-center"><div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex"><textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="3"></textarea></div></td>';
        cols += '<td class="col-1 border"><div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-dark" id ="deleteRow"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div></td></tr>';

        // Insert the columns inside a row
        newRow.append(cols);

        
        // Insert the row inside a table
        $('#tabl tr:last').before(newRow);

    });

    // Remove row when delete btn is clicked
    $("table").on("click", "#deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    flex: 8;
  }

  .form-inline label {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Invoice</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <form method="POST" action="genpdf.php">
    <div class="table-responsive bg-light">
    <table id="tabl" class="table table-borderless border border-dark">
    
    <tbody>
    
        <tr class="d-flex border">
      <td class="col-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/c.png" style="max-height: 120px!important;"/>
      </td>
      <td class="col-6">
      <h2>words here</h2>
         <p class="font-italic">words here<br />
            words here</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-4">
         <p class="text-right">
         words here
         </p>
      <div class="form-group form-inline justify-content-end d-flex">
        <label for="gstin">words here</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gstin">
        </div>
      </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-6 border">
      <p>wh</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rec">wh</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="rec" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label for="party">words here</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="party">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-6 border">
    <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">words here</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="date">words here</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">words here</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">words here</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="del">
         <option>words here</option>
         <option>words here</option>
     </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="del">words here</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="del">
        </div>
      </td>
        </tr>
       
      <tr class="d-flex">
       <td class="col-12 border">
          words here
       </td>
      </tr>
      <div>
       <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-2 border">
      <p class="justify-content-center d-flex">one</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-4 border">
      <p class="justify-content-center d-flex">two</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-2 border">
       <p class="justify-content-center d-flex">three</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-3 border">
       <p class="justify-content-center d-flex">four</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1 border">
      <div class="justify-content-center d-flex"></div>
      </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
         <tr class="d-flex" id="rw">
      <td class="col-2 border">
      <div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="slno">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-4 border text-center">
      <div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-2 border text-center">
      <div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quan">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-3 border text-center">
       <div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="remr" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1 border">
      <div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex"><button class="btn btn-dark" id ="deleteRow"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>
      </td>
        </tr>
         
         <tr class="d-flex">
         <td class="col-12 border">
         <button class="btn btn-dark" id="insertRow" href="#">Add New Row</button>
         </td>
         </tr> 

         
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-5">
      <p>words here</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-3">
      </td>
      <td class="col-4">
      <p>words here</p><br />
        <p>words here</p>
      </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-5">
      <p>words here</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-3">
      </td>
      <td class="col-4">
      <p>words here</p><br />
        <p>words here</p>
      </td>
    </tr> 
        
    </tbody>
    
</table>
  </div>  
  </form>
  </div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, i got the answer for this question in another post, ty @rahularyansharma

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944227/14472274

Comment: Yes, that already solved my question, i already linked that page on the 1st comment, ty