# Add row to the beginning of a table - JavaScript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best method in jQuery to add an additional row to a table as the first row?

I have a table like this

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="but">mybutton</button>
```

I want to add a row **as the first row** to the beginning of the table with given default values. How can I accomplish this using JavaScript and jQuery? A fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `$("mytable").html("<tr>...</tr>" + $("mytable").html())` ?

Comment: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/01/jquery-append-table-row-at-first-and.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/32Ymw/

```
$("#but").click(function(){
   row = $("<tr></tr>");
   col1 = $("<td>col1</td>");
   col2 = $("<td>col2</td>");
   col3 = $("<td>col3</td>");
   row.append(col1,col2,col3).prependTo("#mytable");   
});​
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use .prepend function in jQuery.

```
$('#mytable').prepend($('<tr>'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 8):

Using `.on('click',...);` and `prepend`:
http://jsfiddle.net/k8hCa/

jQuery:

```
$('#but').on('click', function(e){
    $('#mytable').prepend('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good, but it is definitely worth noting that the tbody is the node you should append/prepend to, and using the appendTo and prependTo methods is the best solution as it will work when there are any number of rows, including zero.

See this answer for a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353736/2812428

Note also that it is good practice to specify a tbody yourself, even if there are no rows, to avoid the issue that there would be no tbody automatically in the DOM in the case that there were no rows added to the table.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method should work

```
$('#mytable').prepend($('<tr>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Folloing is what I am doing

**Template**

```
<script type="text/template" id="cardTemplate">
    <TR class=Normal>
        <TD>
                {0}
        </TD>
        <TD>
                {1}
        </TD>
        <TD>
                {2}
        </TD>

     </TR>
</script>
```

**jQuery**

```
       String.prototype.format = function() {
                                 var args = arguments;
                                 return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
                                        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
                                               ? args[number]
                                               : match
                                              ;
                                          });
                                  };

                var cardTemplate = $("#cardTemplate").html();
                //Note: format is a custom method added for "String"
                var template = cardTemplate.format("a", "b","c");

                //$('#tblScanResult tbody > tr:first').before(template);
                $('#tblScanResult tbody').prepend(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is really ancient but just for the sake of completeness, if you have headers, you can easily modify Alex answer to insert at the top of the body rows but after the headers rows thusly...

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="but">mybutton</button>

$('#but').on('click', function(e){
    $('#mytable > tbody').prepend('<tr><td>newcol1</td><td>newcol2</td><td>newcol3</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript way of adding a new row at the top of a table is as simple as:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var row = myTable.insertRow(1);  // Give index as 1

var cell1= row.insertCell(0);
var cell2= row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = "Contents in cell1";
cell2.innerHTML = "Contents in cell2";
```

Give the index for the `insertRow()` method as `1`.