# Adding row dynamically - append row from above

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mans">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="item[]" id="11" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="recommendations[]" id="12" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="importance[]" id="13" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="14" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

add row

http://jsfiddle.net/yKjuw/283/

I have been going through most of these questions and as I have no idea what I am doing. Using the fiddle above you can see the name attribute amends to to ID of the FIRST table td. I need the name of each column to remain the same going down. I tried to add other variables with td:second td:third but the function failed to work at all. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a row on top of table generated by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353657/add-a-row-on-top-of-table-generated-by-javascript)

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat the linked Question, I believe, is not what he is asking, he is looking to keep the `name` attributes the same on each row. His Fiddle is working correctly

Comment: nothing like that mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name of the input based on the last row and index of current input element like

```
function addTableRow(jQtable) {
  var $row = jQtable.find("tr:last"),
    $inputs = $row.find('input');
  var lastId = $row.find("td:first input").attr("id");
  var newId = parseInt(lastId) + 10;

  var row = $('<tr />');

  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    var thisId = newId + i;
    var cell = $('<td />');
    var label = $('<label for="' + thisId + '">' + thisId + '</label>');
    var input = $('<input type="text" name="' + $inputs.eq(i).attr('name') + '" id="' + thisId + '" />');
    cell.append(label, input);
    row.append(cell);
  }
  row.append('<td><a href="#">del</a></td>');
  jQtable.append(row);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fuu9e70L/)

---

You can use `.clone()` to simplify this

```
function addTableRow(jQtable) {
  var $row = jQtable.find("tr:last"),
    $clone = $row.clone().appendTo(jQtable);

  $clone.find('[id]').attr('id', function(i, id) {
    return 10 + +id;
  });
  $clone.find('label').remove();
  $clone.find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).before('<label for="' + this.id + '">' + this.id + '</label>')
  })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fuu9e70L/2/)

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. This answer has also helped me with a load of other of my isses with input dynamics. Merci

Comment: i'll get reading about .clone() seems to be what I have been missing.

Answer (score 0):

Or this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjrumne7/)

Use clone, its simple. [jQuery clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
function addTableRow(e) {
    var row = $('#mans tr:last');
        row = row.clone(true);
        row.find('>td>input').each(function(){
            var t = $(this), id = t.attr('id'), new_id = id*1+10;
            t.attr('id',new_id);
        });
    $('#mans').append(row);
}
function removeRow(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
$(function () {
    $('#addRow').on('click', addTableRow);
    $('table tr>td>a').on('click', removeRow);
});
```